# Ruby Program time conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The task is to Write a method that will take in a number of minutes, and returns a string that formats the number into `hours:minutes`.

here's what I have so far:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
minutes = (minutes / 60) % 60
hours = minutes / (60 * 60)
format(" %02d:%02d ", hours, minutes)
return format
end
```

it's not working out for me

Comment: @takendarkk seing his solution not working mean not getting the expected result

Comment: @SocoM Of course. But is it incorrect output? An error? Something else? There are lots of ways to "_not get the expected result_" as you put it.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and "[ask]". What does "not working out for me" mean? Where is your input data and the expected output? I'd strongly recommend getting in the habit of indenting your code correctly; It's a great help when debugging and when showing others your code, especially when you begin writing more complex code.

Comment: Is `minutes / (60 * 60)` really the way to figure out how many hours are in that many minutes? How many minutes are in an hour?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def time_conversion(time)
    minutes = time % 60
    hours = time / 60
    minutes = (minutes < 10)? "0" + minutes.to_s : minutes.to_s
    return hours.to_s + ":" + minutes
end
```

Using division in Ruby returns a whole number, lowered to the previous number. Using modulus returns the remainder after division.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's [`Numeric#divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) is exactly what you want here. It returns both the quotient and remainder of a division operation, so e.g. `66.divmod(60)` returns `[ 1, 6 ]`. Combined with [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) (or [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/String.html#method-i-25), it makes for an extremely simple solution:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  "%02d:%02d" % minutes.divmod(60)
end

puts time_conversion(192)
# => 03:12
```

Answer (score -1):

Well try

```
h = minutes/60
M = minutes%60
```

Comment: Why? Explain. Don't throw out code, instead show why it's useful.

Comment: Not sure how I can help here but what he is looking for is a solution for a simple math question not programming one!

Comment: can you please explain the following, how it works....im new to coding and haven't gotten to the point to know what the question mark does here... thanks alot  minutes = (minutes < 10)? "0" + minutes.to_s : minutes.to_s

Comment: It was @Richard answer and it's basically if you have less the 10minutes it add/append 0 so the example of 66 became 1:06 and not 1:6

Comment: It's a one line of/else statement it mean if minutes < 10 then going to add 0 in the begin else we let the minutes

Comment: @SocoM "what he is looking for is a solution for a simple math question not programming one!" Then that would make it off-topic for Stack Overflow and on-topic for one of the many math-related sites. But, since the question is phrased using code it IS a code programming one. That there are math errors doesn't change that.

Comment: here's the testing codes to get true for all three line. but when I tried Richard Hamilton's code it gave me true for the first test line and false for the rest 2:   puts('time_conversion(15) == "0:15": ' + (time_conversion(15) == '0:15').to_s)
puts('time_conversion(150) == "2:30": ' + (time_conversion(150) == '2:30').to_s)
puts('time_conversion(360) == "6:00": ' + (time_conversion(360) == '6:00').to_s)

Comment: and when I tried Mihail Petkov's code it gave me the following errors using the same testing codes above:  
/home/ubuntu/workspace/ruby practice_time_conversion.rb:4:in `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/ruby practice_time_conversion.rb:4:in `time_conversion'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/ruby practice_time_conversion.rb:7:in `<main>'

Comment: Actually @richaed had a mistaken using the var name minutes (hours is getting the minutes only )so just change it and it will work ( https://repl.it/BaW1/2 ) (I will try to correct his answer)

Comment: i would like to write the following line in a if statement because that's how my instructor wants it. i tried alot but i can't figure it out. can someone help please:  minutes = (minutes < 10)? "0" + minutes.to_s : minutes.to_s

Comment: Https://repl.it/BaW1/3  (hope you can understand the one line if statement)

Comment: i tried it and im still gettng this:  time_conversion(15) == "0:15": true
time_conversion(150) == "2:30": false
time_conversion(360) == "6:00": false